# Expanded securityadmin

Tags: sql-server-2005, security-roles

I'm aware that sysadmin is documented as the server role necessary for creating logins (SQL/Windows-integrated); nevertheless, I'm tasked to find out if there's any *other* server role (built-in or otherwise) that can be used.

To be specific, I'm looking to setup one or two logins with access to create logins, create [database] users, assign users to [database] roles. Potentially reset passwords, but most of the logins are Windows-integrated and it's not necessary. *Cannot* have access to data at all, nor can these logins have rights to update tables nor create/update roles.

Seems my only options so far are to set these 2 logins with securityadmin server role and for the specific databases, configure with db_securityadmin and db_accessadmin... but this configuration doesn't allow for creating logins.

Comment: Kind of thinking it's not possible then... :(